# How to make WorkManager alive when app is killed?

Tags: android, android-workmanager, workmanagers

I am downloading file with "Coroutine Worker" work Manager, when application is in background the downloading work properly but when application is killed, work Manager stop working.

I tried to keep it alive with a boolean variable in an infinite loop to make it work but it didn't work as well.

```
class UploadWorker(
    private val appContext: Context,
    workerParams: WorkerParameters
) : CoroutineWorker(appContext, workerParams) {
    private var isDownloadCompleted = false


    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        val filName = inputData.getString("filName") ?: ""
        val url = inputData.getString("URL") ?: ""

        /*when file is downloaded, I change the status of the boolean to true, so it break the 
          loop*/

        //Loop break when download file is completed, occur error, or pause.
        while (!isDownloadCompleted) {
            Log.e("tag**", "downloaded file $isDownloadCompleted")
        }

        // Indicate whether the work finished successfully with the Result
        return Result.success()
    }

}
```

```
val imageData = workDataOf("URL" to url, "filName" to filName)
        val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(false)
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .setRequiresStorageNotLow(false)
            .build()
        Log.e("tag**", "createReq")

        val uploadWorkRequest: WorkRequest =
            OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<UploadWorker>()
                .setInputData(imageData)
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .setInitialDelay(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .setBackoffCriteria(
                    BackoffPolicy.LINEAR,
                    OneTimeWorkRequest.MIN_BACKOFF_MILLIS,
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                )
                .build()
```

I wanted to make it work whether application is killed or in background.

Comment: Didn't Understand the question, are you saying that u want to perform downloading even when the application is killed?

Comment: the file is downloaded if application is not killed or is in background, but if application is killed then it won't work. Workmanager suppose to work even app is killed.

Comment: I think it has something to do with your work request, since your work request in a time request,You could try replacing it with a PeriodicWorkRequest which will run after every x time regardless of app's state (only if the app is not force closed)

Comment: For any task that you are going to perform while app is killed, You need to make foreground service and that is the only way to perform task when app is killed or not in the RAM.

Comment: @MAshhal It did not work, when application is closed from background, the work manager execution stop when i reopen the application its execution start where it stopped. but It has to work even app is killed.

Comment: @KaranMehta In Work Manager Docs, work manager never stop if you not return the status which will be Success or Failure.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps you ->

**Kotlin ->**

```kotlin
class UploadWorker(
        private val appContext: Context,
        workerParams: WorkerParameters
    ) : CoroutineWorker(appContext, workerParams) {
        private var isDownloadCompleted = false


        override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
            val filName = inputData.getString("filName") ?: ""
            val url = inputData.getString("URL") ?: ""

            /*when file is downloaded, I change the status of the boolean to true, so it break the
              loop*/

            //Loop break when download file is completed, occur error, or pause.
            while (!isDownloadCompleted) {
                Log.e("tag**", "downloaded file $isDownloadCompleted")
            }

            // Indicate whether the work finished successfully with the Result
            return Result.success()
        }

    }
```

Instead of using OneTimeWorkRequest, Try Using PeriodicWorkRequest, Hope it works.

```kotlin
val imageData = workDataOf("URL" to url, "filName" to filName)
        val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(false)
            .setRequiresStorageNotLow(false)
            .build()

        Log.e("tag**", "createReq")

        val uploadWorkRequest: WorkRequest =
            PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<UploadWorker>(2, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                .setInputData(imageData)
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .setInitialDelay(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .setBackoffCriteria(
                    BackoffPolicy.LINEAR,
                    OneTimeWorkRequest.MIN_BACKOFF_MILLIS,
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                )
                .build()
```

Comment: I tried, but it did not work, when application is closed from background, the work manager execution stop when i reopen the application its execution start where it stopped.
but It has to work even app is killed.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing says that WorkManager will work if the app is killed. If the app is killed it is dead. That's it. What WorkManager ensures is that:

- the application is less likely to be killed while a Work is in progress because WorkManager raised its own Service
- If the application is killed and respectively a work is stopped - WM will ensure that the Work will be resumed in a later stage and it will finish for sure at some point when the Constraints are met.

Comment: But we can keep work manager alive with notification manager, its working on Google Pixel and other mobiles but not not Infinix, Redmi..

Answer (score 0):

All things are good but I forgot to attached a notification with Work Manager.

```
class UploadWorker(
    private val appContext: Context,
    workerParams: WorkerParameters
) : CoroutineWorker(appContext, workerParams) {
    private var isDownloadCompleted = false


    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(
            applicationContext,
            appContext.getString(R.string.channel_name)
        )
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText("0MB/ $fileSize")
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setProgress(100, 0, false)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
        
        
        val filName = inputData.getString("filName") ?: ""
        val url = inputData.getString("URL") ?: ""
        //attach your notification, so workmanager will be killed
        setForegroundAsync(ForegroundInfo(id, notification.build()))

        /*when file is downloaded, I change the status of the boolean to true, so it break the 
          loop*/

        //Loop break when download file is completed, occur error, or pause.
        while (!isDownloadCompleted) {
            Log.e("tag**", "downloaded file $isDownloadCompleted")
        }

        // Indicate whether the work finished successfully with the Result
        return Result.success()
    }

}
```

Comment: So now everything works as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using oneTimeWorkRequest, try using setExpediated(true) while building the work request.

Note: setExpediated(true) cannot be set for a periodic work request.